# is it possible to lock row in PostgreSQL 13 database

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that store the music metadata. I want the music metadata ensure by human, did not allow modify. is it possible to make the PostgreSQL table row static and did not allow modify? make some row to archive mode.

Answer (score 1):

Since no User should *ever* be rummaging around inside your database, then this is an *Application* issue.

How you "archive" records is entirely up to you.

- You could use a simple flag field that, once set, tells the *Application* not to allow changes.
- You could *partition* your table into "active" and "archived" records.
- You could use a completely *separate* table for the "archived" stuff.

If your users *do* have access to the database, then they should *only* be granted read-only permissions so that can't change anything, even if they wanted to.  The Application, of course, should use *its own* account, which is granted update permissions as well.